# I want to insert value in text box but as the elements are dynamically created, I'm unable to define the element id in the javascript

Tags: python, html, django, scripting

I want to populate the text area with some text. I wrote a script which does this on a button click. The bottleneck here is that the elements of the HTML are dynamic and are created as per the user's count working on it. Well, my script works for a static text area. How can i make my script helpful for dynamic text area.

```
  function insertText(elemID, text)
  {     
    var elem = document.getElementById(elemID);
    elem.innerHTML += text;
  }

</script>

<input type="button" name="review_type" value="Postitive"  onclick="insertText('txt1', 'Negative - ')"; /> 
<input type="button" name="review_type" value="Nagative" onclick="insertText('txt1', 'Positive - ')"; />
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is the code that I use to generate the text area dynamically     <div class="span-16 last" style="padding-top:5px">
           <ul>
               {% for user in users %} </ul>

Answer (score 0):

i can't clear what you want but i will try my best.if you want working on exact element that client pushing on it  you can pass element to javascript function like this:

```
<input type="button" name="review_type" value="Postitive"  onclick="insertText(this)" data-text="any text you want" data-foo = "bar"  data-state ="Positive - " />
```

and then in javascript do what you want on this element:

```
  function insertText(element){
   let text = $(element).data("text") # get from 'data-text' attribute
   $(element).text = text; # assign to input
    # do what you want with this element like:
   let input_value = $(element).val()  # result ====> input_value = "Postitive"
   let state =  $(element).data("state") # result ====> state = "Positive - "
   let new_value = $(element).data("foo") #result ===> new_value = "bar"
}
```

maybe helping you.and try working with jQuery . its simple than javascript to select elements and capturing and changing on elements.

Comment: Thanks Mehdi for a reply. What I am trying here is to insert value like positive or negative in the text area on button click. The issue is that the text area gets generated dynamically due to which I'm unable to define an id to that element. Due to which, I'm not able to insert the value in every text area generated dynamically.

Comment: it isn't matter how <input> is generate . by my way you can have access to clickeded <input> by `onclick = "insertText(this)"` . when you use word `this` in function you can pass active element to function and doing what you want on that element alone  .

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: insertText is not defined is thrown when we use this as we are trying to fill a text area with a button click.

Comment: where did you put this function? in same .html file in <script> </script> tag?or in .js file?

Comment: In the same file.

Answer (score 0):

Got It, it's working well. Below is the solution-

In your dynamically changing HTML element, add the following code-

```
<textarea style="height: auto" rows="1" id="txt{{user.id}}" />
```

Add txt{{user.id}} for fetching id of the dynamic text area -

```
<input type="button" name="review_type" value="Postitive"  onclick="insertText('txt{{user.id}}', 'Positive - ')"; /> 
<input type="button" name="review_type" value="Nagative" onclick="insertText('txt{{user.id}}', 'Negative - ')"; />
```